# Plugin for browse the functions and variables in Gvim

Tags: vim

Can someone recommend a good plugin for browsering the functions and variables of sources files in Gvim?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the most popular plugins is [TagList](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273). It provides a simple
and intuitive way to browse an automatically generated list of tags
for a buffer. There are also less popular alternatives like [Source
Explorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2179) or [ttags](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2018), but I would recommend to try TagList
first. It is simple to use yet powerful enough, and probably will fit
your demands.

Answer (score 0):

Vim is provide very fast and powerful way to navigate in big code base.

Read about :

- Ctags
- Cscope
- OmniComplete

[Here](http://apowerfullvim.blogspot.com/) i have written a brief about how to use cscope and ctags with Vim.